# Fixing this if,else statements

Tags: c, char

The problems seem to be on

> Line 18: warning: comparison between pointer and integer
>   Line 22: error: expected expression before 'else'

What am I doing wrong? Is there a better way of doing this?

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char pname[25];
    char Y[1];
    char N[1];
    char choice[1];

    printf("when responding to Yes or No questions use Y/N.\n");
    printf("Hello,traveler Welcome to the Castle of Atal...."
            "What is your name?\n");
    scanf("%s", &pname);

    printf("Greeting's %s What bring's you to the kingdom of Tharnos?\n",
            pname);
    printf("I see how intresting do you wish to enter %s ?\n", pname);
    scanf("%c", &choice);

    if (choice == 'Y');
        printf("Enter %s...\n", pname);
    else (choice == 'N');
        printf("Farewell lost soul!\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: choice == 'Y' compares a pointer to an integer 'Y' , are you intend to compare with choice[0] which is a character.

Answer (score 8):

In your code, change the definitions

```
char Y [1];
char N [1];
char choice[1];
```

to

```
 char Y;
 char N;
 char choice;
```

Otherwise, with the current definition, `choice` represents an `array` (of 1 element), which

- is not required here, a single `char` will work just fine.
- will trigger the warning for doing `choice == 'Y'`, because, you cannot compare array with `==` operator.

That said,

1. `scanf ("%c",&choice);` should be `scanf (" %c",&choice);` to avoid the previous `newline`.
2. `scanf ("%s",&pname);` should be `scanf ("%24s",pname);` to avoid buffer overrun.

and , as mentioned [in the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30325648/2173917) by Mr. **@iharob**,

3. `if (choice == 'Y');`should be `if (choice == 'Y')` (the `;` removed), otherwise, the `if` statement is effectively useless.
4. There is no *conditional expression evaluation* for `else`. You can make use of `else if(choice == 'N')`, though.

Comment: Thank you dude will try that now :)  appreciated (Update) ran it fixed the error on line 18 but line 22 keeps telling me expected expression before 'else' which is odd

Comment: Again thank you dude not sure what a buffer overrun is must the new changes have done the job i guess i have a lot to learn :)

Comment: Just another quick thing when i tried to compile it the \n  newline char wasn't creating a new line is that because of me or the compiler ??

Comment: @marmaa Info about the problems with scanf and buffer overruns can be found in the [C FAQ](http://c-faq.com/stdio/scanfprobs.html).

Comment: @marmaa what do you mean by `\n newline char wasn't creating a new line`? can you elaborate on this so that we can help you?

Comment: @SouravGhosh Correct the revised code now works for example in code pad the \n was working fine but when I compiled it to see if it worked as a program it just printed the \n?

Answer (score 6):

Your if statement do have issues

1. You should not put a semicolon at the end of an if statement, that would mean an if statement with an empty code block.
2. The syntax

   ```
   else (choice == 'N');
   ```

   is wrong, there is an equivalent though

   ```
   else if (choice == 'N');
   /*   ^ you should add `if' after `else' */
   ```

Your code has more problems, but you didn't ask about them. @[SouravGhosh](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30325607/1983495) did address them anyway.

Comment: Thank's for your input :) appreciated this community is really nice.

Comment: @iharob Yes, I do agree with your point. You're the one who first adressed the issues mentioned in your answer. I've simply added them to my answer to make it complete. Kudos and thanks. :-)

Answer (score 4):

Remove the semi-colons.

```
if (choice == 'Y');  <----- remove this semicolon
 { 
     printf ("Enter %s...\n",pname);
 }
```

The above is equivalent to:

```
if( choice == 'Y')
  ;  /* Do nothing */
printf( ... );
else  /* syntax error, not paired with an if statement */
  ;
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation as to the removal of the  semicolon apprecited dude.

Answer (score 2):

Your syntax in not correct, you should use the right syntax:

```c
if (condition) {

} else if (condition) {

}
```

or you can use this if you have something default to do when none of your conditions are true:

```c
if (condition) {

} else if (condition) {

} else {
    // you will get in this if when all of your conditions become false 
}
```